# Cannot add qmake files to Qt Versions [armhf]

Tags: c++, qt, arm, qt-creator, qmake

I installed qt4-qmake:armhf and qt5-qmake:armhf but I cannot add it to Qt Versions in Qt Creator manually. I get error:

> The qmake executable could not be added: qmake""is not an executable.

What else should I try?

Comment: What OS and what path did did you add?

Comment: Debian, /usr/bin/qmake @DragosPop

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows right now, but searching file list for the 2 packages in debian repository online it seems that that qmake is located in:

- /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 for qt4
- /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmake
  for qt5